# Converting an html file into pdf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to convert an html file into PDF file in client-side code. Steps are:

1. Getting link to an html file in response to an API.
2. Convert that file into a PDF file.
3. Display link to view/download that PDF file.

After some search I found that I should use jsPDF or pdfmake but in those I was only able to manually write content but was not able convert html file to PDF.

```
let element = <HTMLScriptElement>document.getElementsByClassName("pvtTable")[0];

html2canvas(element)
  .then((canvas: any) => {
    doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), "JPEG", 0, 50, doc.internal.pageSize.width, element.offsetHeight / 5);
    doc.save(`Report-${Date.now()}.pdf`);
  })
```

Here I cannot get the content of by using `getElementsByClassName()` method. How can I convert file without using this.

Comment: Can you update post with some html.I wanted to clarify that are you trying to export a custom component to PDF

Comment: @SamuelJMathew Not component actually. I am simply getting URL to a file stored somewhere online. That file is of html extension. I have to convert it to a PDF.

Comment: This code is not sufficient to understand your requirement pls give a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @NareshMobarsa The  `cannot get the content of by using getElementsByClassName() method` sentence is revealing. It means you might be trying to get that table element before it's rendered. Try wrapping your `html2canvas(element)` call in a function, and then only call that function once you load the HTML file and put it in the pvtTable[0].

Answer (score 1):

try DOMpdf... this should be a comment, dont have enough rep though